# Finding an element in a set that uses a struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, set

I'm creating the 8-puzzle in C++. I take the puzzle based on input, then create a set containing the puzzle. The set uses a struct to hold the x,y coordinates along with the id. This is my struct:

```
struct tile {
int id;
int xCord;
int yCord;

tile(int a, int b, int c) :
    id(a),
    xCord(b),
    yCord(c) {}


bool operator<(const tile& Rhs) const {

    if (xCord < Rhs.xCord)
        return true;
    else if (xCord > Rhs.xCord)
        return false;
    else if (xCord == Rhs.xCord) {
        if (yCord < Rhs.yCord)
            return true;
        else if (yCord < Rhs.yCord)
            return false;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

void print() const {
    cout << "Node - id=" << id << " Coordinates=(" << xCord << "," << yCord << ")" << endl;
}
};
```

At this point, I need to shuffle the puzzle, which involves finding the the empty tile, which has an id of `0`. I can't figure out how to use the `find` function with how I have setup my set.

So far I have used this, but there is a syntax error:

```
set<tile>::iterator it = puzzleSet.find(0);
```

Here is my set declaration:

```
set<tile> puzzleSet;
```

Could anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: no instance of overloaded function "std::set<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [with _Kty=tile, _Pr=std::less<tile>, _Alloc=std::allocator<tile>]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (int) @NeilButterworth

Comment: Time complexity is a big issue in this problem. I can't afford to loop through the entire set.

Comment: Added the set declaration.

Comment: std::set::find() takes a Key&, not an integer. Why are you giving it a 0? You should give it a tile object (which it will accept as reference).

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham That entire `operator <` could be just this: -- `bool operator<(const tile& Rhs) const { return std::tie(xCord, yCord) < std::tie(Rhs.xCord, Rhs.yCord); }`

Answer (score 1):

your set is ordered by coordinates so your set cannot help you to find by id.
possible solution:
`std::find_if(puzzleSet.begin(), puzzleSet.end(), [id](puzzleSet const & item){ return item.id == id; });`

if the linear search is too expensive. you can add another set that is ordered by id. or try to order your set by id and coordinats (if applicable)

---

a small typo in your code:

```
if (yCord < Rhs.yCord)
        return true;
    else if (yCord < Rhs.yCord) // here should be >
        return false;
```

Comment: The reason I chose to order by coordinates was so that I knew exactly where the tile to be moved was in the set. So if I needed to move a tile left, I knew that THAT tile was next in the set, if I'm looking from the empty tile's perspective. If I ordered by ID, I would have no idea where to find the tile with coordinates (x,y+1), meaning I would have to search the set yet again causing the same issue I'm having now.

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham i do not know if applicable but for x*y board representation you can use a simple `vector<tile>` and calculate the index in this vector as `y*board_width + x`. and in addition to the vector you can add a `map<id, index>` or `map<id, coordinate>`. Thus you get linear representation of the board and ease of searching by id

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but linear search will be too much with my problem.

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham linear search of what? if you search by coordinates - there is no search at all - simple direct access

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because the `set<tile>::find` expects another `tile`, not an `int`. C++14 added new overloads that allow searching by another type, see [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find). That source also says that to enable them, `set`'s comparator must be *transparent*. Default comparator is `std::less<tile>` that to my knowledge is not explicitly said to be transparent. So the solution is to define custom comparator:

```
struct comp
{
public:
    using is_transparent = void;//Can be anything, just needs to be defined.
    constexpr bool operator()(const tile &lhs, const tile &rhs) const
    {
        return lhs < rhs;//You should reimplement to create proper ordering.
    }
    constexpr bool operator()(const tile &lhs, int ID) const
    {
        return lhs.ID < ID;//You should reimplement to create proper ordering.
    }
    constexpr bool operator()(int ID, const tile &rhs) const
    {
        return ID < rhs.ID;//You should reimplement to create proper ordering.
    }
};
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::string buffer = "a s d f ";
    std::cout << "Before " << buffer << std::endl;
    std::set<tile, comp> set;
    set.find(0);//Should compile and find the tile with zero ID
}
```

**Note** the comparator must create the **same** weak-ordering for **all** overloads to work correctly. Your implementation of `operator<` does not, because as @Alexander pointed out in their answer, your tiles are not sorted by IDs.

EDIT: So don't use the comp as it is now, you should change the implementation to create the ordering correctly.